# mySQL >> Very Slow Query with CONCAT, GROUP_CONCAT and multiple JOINS (100 sec for 63 records)

Tags: mysql, performance, join, indexing, group-concat

I am using the following query:

```
SELECT *,  
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct t_name order by t_id separator ', ') 'Topics', 
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct ch_title order by ch_id separator ', ') 'Chapters', 
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct cs_code order by cs_id separator ', ') 'ContentStandards', 
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct c_name order by c_id separator ', ') 'Categories', 
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct s_name order by s_id separator ', ') 'SchoolSubjects' 
FROM (
SELECT r.res_id, r.res_status, r.res_type, r.res_category, r.res_title, r.res_filename, r.res_source, r.res_gradelevel_from, r.res_gradelevel_to, r.res_tags, r.res_description, r.res_onserver, r.res_favoriteaccts, r.res_CreatedOn, c_id, s_id, t_id, ch_id, cs_id, 
CONCAT("<a class=""ReportLink"" href=""page.asp?category=",c_name,""" title=""",c_name,""">",c_name,"</a>") as c_name, 
CONCAT("<a class=""ReportLink"" href=""page.asp?subject=",s_name,""" title=""",s_name,""">",s_name,"</a>") as s_name, 
CONCAT("<a class=""ReportLink"" href=""page.asp?topic=",t_name,""" title=""",t_name,""">",t_name,"</a>") as t_name, 
CONCAT("<a class=""ReportLink"" href=""page.asp?cs=",cs_code,""" title=""",cs_code,""">",cs_code,"</a>") as cs_code, 
CONCAT("<a class=""ReportLink"" href=""page.asp?chapter=",ch_title,""" title=""",ch_title,""">",ch_code,": ",ch_title,"</a>") as ch_title 
FROM hre_resources r 
LEFT JOIN topic_to_resource ttr ON ttr.rt_resourceid = r.res_id 
LEFT JOIN topics t on t.t_id = ttr.rt_topicid 
LEFT JOIN topic_to_cs tcs on tcs.cst_topicid = t.t_id 
LEFT JOIN categories c ON c_id = r.res_category 
LEFT JOIN topic_to_framework ttc on ttc.ft_topicid = t.t_id 
LEFT JOIN ca_hss_frameworkchapters ch ON ch.ch_id = ttc.ft_frameworkid 
LEFT JOIN ca_hss_contentstandards cs ON cs.cs_id = tcs.cst_contentstandardid 
LEFT JOIN schoolsubjects_to_resource str ON str.sr_resid = r.res_id 
LEFT JOIN schoolsubjects s ON s.s_id = str.sr_sid) links 
WHERE RES_Status = 'Active' 
GROUP BY RES_ID 
ORDER BY RES_Title ASC, RES_Source DESC
```

This query returns 64 perfectly formatted records from our mySQL DB, but it takes over 100 seconds to do this.

The query profiler shows the key offenders as:

```
+-------------------------------+-----------+
|         Sending data          | 34.530026 |
+-------------------------------+-----------+
| Creating sort index           | 24.205878 |
| Storing result in query cache | 56.739204 |
+-------------------------------+-----------+
```

The EXPLAIN results are below:

```
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------------+---------+------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type |   table    |  type  | possible_keys |      key      | key_len |                ref                 | rows |                                Extra                                |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------------+---------+------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ref    | <auto_key0>   | <auto_key0>   | 77      | const                              |   10 | Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | r          | ALL    | NULL          | NULL          | NULL    | NULL                               |   64 | NULL                                                                |
|  2 | DERIVED     | ttr        | ref    | RT_ResourceID | RT_ResourceID | 4       | uhri_hre.r.RES_ID                  |    3 | Using where                                                         |
|  2 | DERIVED     | t          | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY       | 4       | uhri_hre.ttr.RT_TopicID            |    1 | Using where                                                         |
|  2 | DERIVED     | tcs        | ref    | CST_TopicID   | CST_TopicID   | 4       | uhri_hre.t.T_ID                    |    9 | Using where                                                         |
|  2 | DERIVED     | c          | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY       | 4       | uhri_hre.r.RES_Category            |    1 | Using where                                                         |
|  2 | DERIVED     | ttc        | ref    | FT_TopicID    | FT_TopicID    | 4       | uhri_hre.t.T_ID                    |   21 | Using where                                                         |
|  2 | DERIVED     | ch         | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY       | 4       | uhri_hre.ttc.FT_FrameworkID        |    1 | Using where                                                         |
|  2 | DERIVED     | cs         | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY       | 4       | uhri_hre.tcs.CST_ContentStandardID |    1 | Using where                                                         |
|  2 | DERIVED     | str        | ref    | SR_RESID      | SR_RESID      | 4       | uhri_hre.r.RES_ID                  |    1 | Using where                                                         |
|  2 | DERIVED     | s          | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY       | 4       | uhri_hre.str.SR_SID                |    1 | Using where                                                         |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------------+---------+------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The tables have the following indexes. Tables not listed have indexes on the ID field (Primary Key):

```
HRE_Resources:
+--------------+-------+--------+--------+--------------+-------------+-----------+------+---------+
|   Keyname    | Type  | Unique | Packed |    Column    | Cardinality | Collation | Null | Comment |
+--------------+-------+--------+--------+--------------+-------------+-----------+------+---------+
| PRIMARY      | BTREE | Yes    | No     | RES_ID       |          64 | A         |      |         |
| RES_Type     | BTREE | No     | No     | RES_Type     |           4 | A         |      |         |
| RES_Category | BTREE | No     | No     | RES_Category |          10 | A         |      |         |
| RES_Status   | BTREE | No     | No     | RES_Status   |           4 | A         |      |         |
| RES_Language | BTREE | No     | No     | RES_Language |           8 | A         |      |         |
| RES_Source   | BTREE | No     | No     | RES_Source   |          21 | A         |      |         |
+--------------+-------+--------+--------+--------------+-------------+-----------+------+---------+

Topics:
+---------+-------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+-----------+------+---------+
| Keyname | Type  | Unique | Packed | Column | Cardinality | Collation | Null | Comment |
+---------+-------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+-----------+------+---------+
| PRIMARY | BTREE | Yes    | No     | T_ID   |          39 | A         |      |         |
| T_Name  | BTREE | No     | No     | T_Name |          39 | A         |      |         |
+---------+-------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+-----------+------+---------+

Topic_to_CS:
+-----------------------+-------+--------+--------+-----------------------+-------------+-----------+------+---------+
|        Keyname        | Type  | Unique | Packed |        Column         | Cardinality | Collation | Null | Comment |
+-----------------------+-------+--------+--------+-----------------------+-------------+-----------+------+---------+
| PRIMARY               | BTREE | Yes    | No     | CST_ID                |         685 | A         |      |         |
| CST_ContentStandardID | BTREE | No     | No     | CST_ContentStandardID |         228 | A         |      |         |
| CST_TopicID           | BTREE | No     | No     | CST_TopicID           |          76 | A         |      |         |
+-----------------------+-------+--------+--------+-----------------------+-------------+-----------+------+---------+

Topic_to_Framework:
+----------------+-------+--------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------+------+---------+
|    Keyname     | Type  | Unique | Packed |     Column     | Cardinality | Collation | Null | Comment |
+----------------+-------+--------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------+------+---------+
| PRIMARY        | BTREE | Yes    | No     | FT_ID          |         471 | A         |      |         |
| FT_TopicID     | BTREE | No     | No     | FT_TopicID     |          22 | A         |      |         |
| FT_FrameworkID | BTREE | No     | No     | FT_FrameworkID |         235 | A         |      |         |
+----------------+-------+--------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------+------+---------+

Topic_to_Resource:
+---------------+-------+--------+--------+---------------+-------------+-----------+------+---------+
|    Keyname    | Type  | Unique | Packed |    Column     | Cardinality | Collation | Null | Comment |
+---------------+-------+--------+--------+---------------+-------------+-----------+------+---------+
| PRIMARY       | BTREE | Yes    | No     | RT_ID         |         387 | A         |      |         |
| RT_ResourceID | BTREE | No     | No     | RT_ResourceID |         129 | A         |      |         |
| RT_TopicID    | BTREE | No     | No     | RT_TopicID    |          77 | A         |      |         |
+---------------+-------+--------+--------+---------------+-------------+-----------+------+---------+

Schoolsubject_to_Resource:
+----------+-------+--------+--------+----------+-------------+-----------+------+---------+
| Keyname  | Type  | Unique | Packed |  Column  | Cardinality | Collation | Null | Comment |
+----------+-------+--------+--------+----------+-------------+-----------+------+---------+
| PRIMARY  | BTREE | Yes    | No     | SR_ID    |         228 | A         |      |         |
| SR_SID   | BTREE | No     | No     | SR_SID   |          25 | A         |      |         |
| SR_RESID | BTREE | No     | No     | SR_RESID |         228 | A         |      |         |
+----------+-------+--------+--------+----------+-------------+-----------+------+---------+

Categories:
+---------+-------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+-----------+------+---------+
| Keyname | Type  | Unique | Packed | Column | Cardinality | Collation | Null | Comment |
+---------+-------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+-----------+------+---------+
| PRIMARY | BTREE | Yes    | No     | C_ID   |           9 | A         |      |         |
| C_Name  | BTREE | No     | No     | C_Name |           9 | A         |      |         |
+---------+-------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+-----------+------+---------+
```

Some of these indexes are created with more complicated WHEREs that are used in other queries.

I have run complex queries on the DB for other purposes that have nothing to do with the query above and it's performing nominally. As such, I don't think it's a server resources issue.

Can anyone see anything in the query above that might be causing such a slow response?

Many thanks in advance!

PS. Adding some info from the server per a request below...

```
+------------------------------+---------+
|        Variable_name         |  Value  |
+------------------------------+---------+
| query_alloc_block_size       | 8192    |
| query_cache_limit            | 1048576 |
| query_cache_min_res_unit     | 4096    |
| query_cache_size             | 1048576 |
| query_cache_type             | ON      |
| query_cache_wlock_invalidate | OFF     |
| query_prealloc_size          | 8192    |
+------------------------------+---------+

+-------------------------+--------+
|      Variable_name      | Value  |
+-------------------------+--------+
| Qcache_free_blocks      |      9 |
| Qcache_free_memory      |  22736 |
| Qcache_hits             | 121910 |
| Qcache_inserts          |   9296 |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes    |   8213 |
| Qcache_not_cached       |  29475 |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache |    103 |
| Qcache_total_blocks     |    295 |
+-------------------------+--------+
```

Comment: Did my best to include all relevant info. Please let me know if I missed something.

Comment: Have you checked the number of the results of the subquery? My guess is you have several unrelated one-to-many relationships involved that are multiplying each other's individual results...and the DISTINCT inside your GROUP_CONCAT is hiding that.

Comment: ...and if that is the case, the usual course of action is to break those joins up into minimal subqueries that are then joined together for the same final result format.

Comment: I agree. Don't try to do everything in one query. That generates huge cartesian products, then you have to reduce that back down using DISTINCT. Instead, just run a few queries, which are individually simpler.

Comment: @Uueerdo, thanks!! The subquery returned 626,242 records, though it took much less time to return (0.0020 sec) than the full query. How would you suggest moving from JOINS to Subqueries?

Comment: Also, I suggest you should not format HTML inside your SQL queries. Just fetch the data back, and use application code to present the data values in HTML.

Comment: I also notice your query spent 50% of your time updating the query cache. I suggest you disable the query cache. The query cache feature has been removed in MySQL 8.0, because of this sort of thing.

Comment: @BillKarwin, thx! Will add SQL_NO_CACHE.

Comment: I meant set `query_cache_type=0` and `query_cache_size=0` in your my.cnf. This disables the query cache globally.

Comment: @nbardach The conversion of the query depends on the actual relationships between the tables (which is not something obvious from the current query). The best way to think of it is to picture the relationships as a "tree" and everywhere you find the tree branching is the point a subquery is needed.

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to know the table relationships because some of your joins don't use aliases in the join conditions. So we have no idea which tables some of the columns belong to. It would help if you show the complete table definitions with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` instead of just showing the indexes.

Comment: Just updated the question with the missing table aliases. Hope that helps!

Comment: Just on first look (viewing on my phone), it looks like you've specified a lot of selected fields in the subquery that you never actually use

Comment: @ChrisJ, thx! These fields are used in the website to display the results of the query. I listed them individually instead of r.* in hopes of improving performance.  Per, Uueerdo's comment, is there anyway to get around the subquery returning 626K records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments above, you seem to be fetching a lot of data from multiple table relationships. This causes several [Cartesian products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), which is why you get the 626K rows.

The solution is to break this up into individual queries.

Here's what I understand about your model:

[image]

Here's what the individual queries would look like, with their respective EXPLAIN plans.

You can see that this eliminates all subqueries and temp tables, it eliminates the Cartesian products so you don't need to use DISTINCT anywhere, and all joins are nicely against primary keys. It might seem repetitive, but the fact that the queries are better optimized should make it run faster.

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT r.res_id, r.res_status, r.res_type, r.res_category, r.res_title, r.res_filename,
  r.res_source, r.res_gradelevel_from, r.res_gradelevel_to, r.res_tags, r.res_description,
  r.res_onserver, r.res_favoriteaccts, r.res_CreatedOn, c.c_name AS 'Categories'
FROM hre_resources AS r
INNER JOIN categories c ON c_id = r.res_category 
WHERE r.res_status = 'Active'
--------------

+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------+------------+---------+---------------------+------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys           | key        | key_len | ref                 | rows | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------+------------+---------+---------------------+------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | r     | ref    | res_status,res_category | res_status | 1       | const               |    1 | Using index condition |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                 | PRIMARY    | 4       | test.r.res_category |    1 | NULL                  |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------+------------+---------+---------------------+------+-----------------------+

EXPLAIN
SELECT r.res_id, GROUP_CONCAT(s.s_name ORDER BY s.s_id SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'SchoolSubjects' 
FROM hre_resources AS r
INNER JOIN schoolsubjects_to_resource str ON str.sr_resid = r.res_id 
INNER JOIN schoolsubjects s ON s.s_id = str.sr_sid
WHERE r.res_status = 'Active' 
GROUP BY r.res_id
--------------

+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------------------+------------+---------+-----------------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                   | key        | key_len | ref             | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------------------+------------+---------+-----------------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | r     | ref    | PRIMARY,res_status,res_category | res_status | 1       | const           |    1 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | str   | ref    | PRIMARY,sr_sid                  | PRIMARY    | 4       | test.r.res_id   |    1 | Using index              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                         | PRIMARY    | 4       | test.str.sr_sid |    1 | NULL                     |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------------------+------------+---------+-----------------+------+--------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

--------------
EXPLAIN
SELECT r.res_id, GROUP_CONCAT(t.t_name ORDER BY t_id SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'Topics'
FROM hre_resources AS r
INNER JOIN topic_to_resource ttr ON ttr.rt_resourceid = r.res_id 
INNER JOIN topics t on t.t_id = ttr.rt_topicid 
WHERE r.res_status = 'Active' 
GROUP BY r.res_id
--------------

+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------------------+------------+---------+---------------------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                   | key        | key_len | ref                 | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------------------+------------+---------+---------------------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | r     | ref    | PRIMARY,res_status,res_category | res_status | 1       | const               |    1 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ttr   | ref    | PRIMARY,rt_topicid              | PRIMARY    | 4       | test.r.res_id       |    1 | Using index              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                         | PRIMARY    | 4       | test.ttr.rt_topicid |    1 | NULL                     |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------------------+------------+---------+---------------------+------+--------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

--------------
EXPLAIN
SELECT r.res_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(ch.ch_code, ':', ch.ch_title) ORDER BY ch.ch_id SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'Chapters'
FROM hre_resources AS r
INNER JOIN topic_to_resource ttr ON ttr.rt_resourceid = r.res_id 
INNER JOIN topics t on t.t_id = ttr.rt_topicid 
INNER JOIN topic_to_framework ttc on ttc.ft_topicid = t.t_id 
INNER JOIN ca_hss_frameworkchapters ch ON ch.ch_id = ttc.ft_frameworkid 
WHERE r.res_status = 'Active' 
GROUP BY r.res_id
--------------

+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------------------+------------+---------+-------------------------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                   | key        | key_len | ref                     | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------------------+------------+---------+-------------------------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | r     | ref    | PRIMARY,res_status,res_category | res_status | 1       | const                   |    1 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ttr   | ref    | PRIMARY,rt_topicid              | PRIMARY    | 4       | test.r.res_id           |    1 | Using index              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                         | PRIMARY    | 4       | test.ttr.rt_topicid     |    1 | Using index              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ttc   | ref    | PRIMARY,ft_frameworkid          | PRIMARY    | 4       | test.ttr.rt_topicid     |    1 | Using index              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ch    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                         | PRIMARY    | 4       | test.ttc.ft_frameworkid |    1 | NULL                     |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------------------+------------+---------+-------------------------+------+--------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

--------------
EXPLAIN
SELECT r.res_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cs.cs_code ORDER BY cs.cs_id SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'ContentStandards'
FROM hre_resources AS r
INNER JOIN topic_to_resource ttr ON ttr.rt_resourceid = r.res_id 
INNER JOIN topics t on t.t_id = ttr.rt_topicid 
INNER JOIN topic_to_cs tcs on tcs.cst_topicid = t.t_id 
INNER JOIN ca_hss_contentstandards cs ON cs.cs_id = tcs.cst_contentstandardid 
WHERE r.res_status = 'Active' 
GROUP BY r.res_id
--------------

+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------------------+------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                   | key        | key_len | ref                            | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------------------+------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | r     | ref    | PRIMARY,res_status,res_category | res_status | 1       | const                          |    1 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ttr   | ref    | PRIMARY,rt_topicid              | PRIMARY    | 4       | test.r.res_id                  |    1 | Using index              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                         | PRIMARY    | 4       | test.ttr.rt_topicid            |    1 | Using index              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tcs   | ref    | PRIMARY,cst_contentstandardid   | PRIMARY    | 4       | test.ttr.rt_topicid            |    1 | Using index              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cs    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                         | PRIMARY    | 4       | test.tcs.cst_contentstandardid |    1 | NULL                     |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------------------+------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+--------------------------+
```

Below is the DDL I assumed for the tables. It would have been helpful if you had included this in your original question.

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
    c_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    c_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'c_name'
);

CREATE TABLE hre_resources (
    res_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    res_category INT NOT NULL,
    res_status ENUM('Active', 'Inactive') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Active',
    res_type VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'type',
    res_title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'title',
    res_filename VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    res_source VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    res_gradelevel_from VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    res_gradelevel_to VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    res_tags VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    res_description VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    res_onserver VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    res_favoriteaccts VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    res_CreatedOn DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '2017-01-01',
    KEY (res_status),
    FOREIGN KEY (res_category) REFERENCES categories(c_id)
);

CREATE TABLE topics (
    t_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    t_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 't_name'
);

CREATE TABLE ca_hss_frameworkchapters (
    ch_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    ch_title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ch_title',
    ch_code VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ch_code'
);

CREATE TABLE ca_hss_contentstandards (
    cs_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    cs_code VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'cs_code'
);

CREATE TABLE schoolsubjects (
    s_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    s_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 's_name'
);

CREATE TABLE topic_to_framework (
    ft_topicid INT NOT NULL,
    ft_frameworkid INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ft_topicid, ft_frameworkid),
    FOREIGN KEY (ft_topicid) REFERENCES topics(t_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (ft_frameworkid) REFERENCES ca_hss_frameworkchapters(ch_id)
);

CREATE TABLE topic_to_resource (
    rt_resourceid INT NOT NULL,
    rt_topicid INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (rt_resourceid, rt_topicid),
    FOREIGN KEY (rt_resourceid) REFERENCES hre_resources (res_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (rt_topicid) REFERENCES topics(t_id)
);

CREATE TABLE topic_to_cs (
    cst_topicid INT NOT NULL,
    cst_contentstandardid INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (cst_topicid, cst_contentstandardid),
    FOREIGN KEY (cst_topicid) REFERENCES topics(t_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (cst_contentstandardid) REFERENCES ca_hss_contentstandards(cs_id)
);

CREATE TABLE schoolsubjects_to_resource (
    sr_resid INT NOT NULL,
    sr_sid INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (sr_resid, sr_sid),
    FOREIGN KEY (sr_resid) REFERENCES hre_resources(res_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (sr_sid) REFERENCES schoolsubjects(s_id)
);
```

---

Here's an example in Python of what I mean by merging the results of multiple queries together.

```
import pprint
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", db="test", cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cur = db.cursor()

res_data = {}

sql = """SELECT r.res_id, r.res_status, r.res_type, r.res_category, r.res_title, r.res_filename, r.res_source, r.res_gradelevel_from, r.res_gradelevel_to, r.res_tags, r.res_description,  r.res_onserver, r.res_favoriteaccts, r.res_CreatedOn, c.c_name AS 'Categories' FROM hre_resources AS r INNER JOIN categories c ON c_id = r.res_category WHERE r.res_status = 'Active'"""
cur.execute(sql)
for row in cur.fetchall():
  res_data[row['res_id']] = row

sql = """SELECT r.res_id, GROUP_CONCAT(s.s_name ORDER BY s.s_id SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'SchoolSubjects' FROM hre_resources AS r INNER JOIN schoolsubjects_to_resource str ON str.sr_resid = r.res_id  INNER JOIN schoolsubjects s ON s.s_id = str.sr_sid WHERE r.res_status = 'Active' GROUP BY r.res_id"""
cur.execute(sql)
for row in cur.fetchall():
  res_data[row['res_id']].update(row)

sql = """SELECT r.res_id, GROUP_CONCAT(t.t_name ORDER BY t_id SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'Topics' FROM hre_resources AS r INNER JOIN topic_to_resource ttr ON ttr.rt_resourceid = r.res_id INNER JOIN topics t on t.t_id = ttr.rt_topicid WHERE r.res_status = 'Active' GROUP BY r.res_id"""
cur.execute(sql)
for row in cur.fetchall():
  res_data[row['res_id']].update(row)

sql = """SELECT r.res_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(ch.ch_code, ':', ch.ch_title) ORDER BY ch.ch_id SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'Chapters' FROM hre_resources AS r INNER JOIN topic_to_resource ttr ON ttr.rt_resourceid = r.res_id INNER JOIN topics t on t.t_id = ttr.rt_topicid INNER JOIN topic_to_framework ttc on ttc.ft_topicid = t.t_id INNER JOIN ca_hss_frameworkchapters ch ON ch.ch_id = ttc.ft_frameworkid WHERE r.res_status = 'Active' GROUP BY r.res_id"""
cur.execute(sql)
for row in cur.fetchall():
  res_data[row['res_id']].update(row)

sql = """SELECT r.res_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cs.cs_code ORDER BY cs.cs_id SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'ContentStandards' FROM hre_resources AS r INNER JOIN topic_to_resource ttr ON ttr.rt_resourceid = r.res_id INNER JOIN topics t on t.t_id = ttr.rt_topicid INNER JOIN topic_to_cs tcs on tcs.cst_topicid = t.t_id INNER JOIN ca_hss_contentstandards cs ON cs.cs_id = tcs.cst_contentstandardid WHERE r.res_status = 'Active' GROUP BY r.res_id"""
cur.execute(sql)
for row in cur.fetchall():
  res_data[row['res_id']].update(row)

db.close()

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()
pp.pprint(res_data)
```

After I added one row of fake data to each table, I got this output from the script above:

```
{2L: {'Categories': 'c_name',
      'Chapters': 'ch_codech_title',
      'ContentStandards': 'cs_code',
      'SchoolSubjects': 's_name',
      'Topics': 't_name',
      'res_CreatedOn': datetime.date(2017, 1, 1),
      'res_category': 1L,
      'res_description': '',
      'res_favoriteaccts': '',
      'res_filename': '',
      'res_gradelevel_from': '',
      'res_gradelevel_to': '',
      'res_id': 2L,
      'res_onserver': '',
      'res_source': '',
      'res_status': 'Active',
      'res_tags': '',
      'res_title': 'title',
      'res_type': 'type'}}
```

Comment: Thanks SO MUCH, Bill! The reason I didn't include the CREATE TABLES is because the hre_resource table is much larger. There's a lot of data in that table that doesn't get used for this view. Re: your solution, how do I wrap this all together so I can loop through a single recordset when I write it to the page?

Comment: Also, I see you've removed the HTML links from the results. How do you suggest I return something like this: <a class="ReportLink" href="page.asp?topic=Children" title="Children">Children</a>, <a class="ReportLink" href="page.asp?topic=Human Rights" title="Human Rights">Human Rights</a>, <a class="ReportLink" href="page.asp?topic=Human Rights Education" title="Human Rights Education">Human Rights Education</a>, etc.

Comment: You should write some application code to run each of the queries, and then merge the results of each query together into some object, one object per `res_id`.

Comment: As for formatting in HTML, I encourage you to do this in application code as well. If you do it in your SQL, it'll become quite annoying as you need to change the HTML from time to time. Keep HTML in your presentation layer, separate from SQL. Use SQL just to fetch raw data.

Comment: Re: "merging the results," I'm genuinely not sure how I can do this. The only way I've gathered data before is by creating a single recordset. Could you please expand the solution to include how my original recordset can be reconstituted?

Comment: Yes, that's what my Python code example above does. Each query result is combined with the row for the same res_id by using Python's  `dict.update()` method. You can do something similar in any other language, I have no idea what language you're using.

Comment: Anyway, I've put in more than enough work on this answer. I haven't even receive an upvote. :-(

Comment: sorry, brother, I had to pick my kids up from school. I am very grateful for your help and happy to give you your due! Cheers, N

Comment: I just implemented your solution and I've found an issue. This is happening with the queries for chapter and content standards. Because different topics overlap with the chapters or content standards they refer to, the results include duplicates. How can I eliminate these duplicates? Please advise. Many thanks! N

Comment: I guess that's a better use of DISTINCT. It shouldn't be as expensive, because it doesn't have to work on 626K rows. Alternative: write application code to reduce the duplicates by using a hash map.

Comment: Thanks, Bill. Can you please update your solution to reflect the need for DISTINCT?

Comment: @nbardach, Fixed. I also fixed the `CONCAT(ch.ch_code, ':', ch.ch_title)` for the Chapters query. It needed some separator between the code and the title.

Answer (score 1):

Start by pulling `WHERE RES_Status = 'Active'` inside the derived table.  That may significantly decrease the size of the tmp table and may significantly shrink the "Creating sort index" phase.

Then focus on the derived table.  Separate it out.  How long does it take?

As for the 56.7s part, it sounds like some settings are too high.  Please provide:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'query%';
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Qc%';
```

Comment: Looks like all the query cache settings are at the default, except it's ON. As I said in a comment at the top, I'd set `query_cache_type=0` and `query_cache_size=0` to disable it.

Comment: Hmmm... The `SHOWs` fail to explain the 56.7s.  As Bill suggests, turn off the QC.  As for the 626K rows, do you get the 'right' answer with `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`?  Start a new Question with _only_ the subquery.